# How does ELF file format defines the stack?

Tags: linux, elf

I'm studying the ELF file format, so I compiled a small program, dumped the section headers and their contents from the resulting executable.

The ELF header contains the entry point address, which points into start of the .text section.

I also found the .data section that contains the static data and .rodata that contains the read only data... I expect there is a section for the stack too, but I can't find that section.

I also expect that at some point ESP is set to the top of some section but I can't find anything like that in the disassembly.

So how does ESP gets its initial value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The following figure describes the memory map of a typical C ELF executable on x86.

[image: Memory map of an C ELF executable on x86]

- The process loads the `.text` and `.data` sections at the base address.
- The **main-stack** is located just below and grows downwards.
- Each thread and function-call will have its **own-stack** / **stack-frame**.
  This is located located below the **main-stack**.
- Each **stack** is separated by a guard page to detect Stack-Overflow.

Hence one does NOT need a dedicated `stack` section in the ELF file.

---

However within the **[man pages for ELF](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)**,  one **does** find a couple of things in an ELF file that control the **stack** attributes. Mainly the executable permissions to the **stack** in memory.

1. `PT_GNU_STACK`
   GNU extension which is used by the Linux kernel to control the state of the stack via the flags set in the `p_flags` member.
2. `.note.GNU-stack`
   This section is used in Linux object files for declaring stack attributes.  This section is of type SHT_PROGBITS. The only attribute used is SHF_EXECINSTR. This indicates to the GNU linker that the object file requires an executable stack.

Comment: So base address == entry point address? So stack grow downwards from that 0x08040000 address? It seems it's at a higher address on that image.

Comment: No. The **entry-point** points to somewhere within the `.text` and has nothing to do with the stack.

Comment: So to sum up, when I'm writing my linker for my pet language (that makes the ELF file), I don't need to worry about the stack because the loader will allocate it and initializes the ESP for me, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. The loader does it. Checkout this [**article**](http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html) that describes the steps the Linux ELF loader undertakes to load an executable into memory.

Comment: To clarify, when you say *Each thread and function-call will have its own-stack.*, do you mean that functions create their own **stack frames**? For threads it makes sense to have a separate stack, however for functions, this doesn't seem to align with my previous knowledge

Comment: Each function-call, not each function. Also, maybe calling it a **stack-frame** makes more sense *(updated the answer)*.