# Stack memory layout in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, stack

I have written a small program for learning about the stack pointer in C. Usually, the stack pointer points to the last address of RAM.  For example, I run this code in Linux, which has the stack pointer in last address (`0x7fffffffffff`) but the variables are stored in these addresses (for this program):

```
c --> 0x7ffc67ca5c94
b --> 0x7ffc67ca5c98
a --> 0x7ffc67ca5c9c
```

Code:

```
void fun(int *ptr)
{
   printf("c --> %p\n",ptr);
   ptr++;
   printf("b --> %p\n",ptr);
   ptr++;
   printf("a --> %p\n",ptr);
}

int main() 
{
   int a = 10,b = 20,c = 30;
   printf("%p     %p    %p\n",&a,&b,&c);
   fun(&c);
   return 0;    
}
```

Output for this program:

```
0x7ffc67ca5c9c     0x7ffc67ca5c98    0x7ffc67ca5c94
c --> 0x7ffc67ca5c94
b --> 0x7ffc67ca5c98
a --> 0x7ffc67ca5c9c
```

My questions are:

1. Why are the variables not stored in last section of the stack frame (0x7fffffffffff) which skips some memory locations and gets stored? Any valid reason for such behavior?
2. Why the stack pointer address has six bytes?

I am working on a 64-bit machine with a 32-bit GCC compiler.

Comment: Where do you get the "stack pointer address has six bytes" from? I see a delta of four bytes as it should be (32 bit addresses, 4 byte alignment).

Comment: The stack pointer can point anywhere the o/s likes as long as the MMU handles it all correctly.  The values you show are similar to what I see on Mac OS X with a 64-bit compiler — it has designed its system differently.  What you see is not the result of using a 32-bit compiler.  There's lots of spare memory space; it's up to the system to decide how to use it.   The stack pointer has 8 bytes, the same as every other pointer.  The most significant pair of bytes are simply zeros, so the `printf()` doesn't add the four leading zeros.

Comment: Side note: none of what you're asking is dictated by the C language standard (but rather depends on compiler implementation).

Comment: The rest of the stack is likely misc crap that desktop computers need for the startup code of the executable? Seems far too much though, surely not even Linux can be that bad?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The virtual addresses for a 32bit program are 32bit even if the CPU could support 64 address ranges. There are no leading zeros, the addresses are actually 32bit wide.

Comment: @dhke: the printed addresses are showing 12 hex digits (48 bits); they're not 32-bit addresses.

Comment: @Lundin Well, if you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278803/how-does-elf-file-format-defines-the-stack), env is in there as well as (probably) any system code mirrored into user space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, I missed that. And of course, the delta is `sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(int *)`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @dhke Well... that's a horrible waste of space. So every Linux executable contains a big chunk of this crap?

Comment: @Lundin I have no idea. For protection you probably need whole pages for parts exposed by the kernel (but those might in the other part of the address space). I'm pretty sure most of these pages are copy-on-write from the parent process or even readonly. You got 48bits worth of address space (on x64). Wasting a few pages (when they are not in physical memory) is probably no bother.

Comment: @SathishRam: try to **compile with optimizations** and look into the generated assembler code (so `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O2 -Wall yourcode.c` then look into `yourcode.s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which has the stack pointer in last address (0x7fffffffffff)

If running a 32bit process, the last address (minus the reserved area) would be `0x7fff ffff` when doing  the *usual* 2GB/2GB split. But 32bit Linux typically reserves only a 1GB kernel address area, so the stack would actually start at `0xc000 0000` (`TASK_SIZE`).

What you are seeing here, instead is the curious split of the x64 address space layout. Here, indeed the user address space ends at `0x0000 7fff ffff ffff`, with `0xffff ff80 0000 0000` and above reserved for the kernel.

Current MMUs actually enforce this, `0xfffe ff80 0000 0000` or similar are not valid addresses, the bit 47-63 must be equal to form a [Canonical Form Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses)

> Why the stack pointer address has six bytes?

It does not look like it does from the output of your program. 
You are printing the size each variable takes on the stack, not the pointer size. The six-byte addresses from `printf()` are actually 64bit-addresses with leading zeros cut off (thanks to @Jonathan Leffler for spotting this).

Indeed, `sizeof(int *) == 8`, but `sizeof(int) == 4`, because even 64bit Linux has [32bit `int`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) (only `long` is 64 bit). It's quite easy to miss that, though.

> Why are the variables not stored in last section of the stack frame (0x7fffffffffff) which skips some memory locations and gets stored? Any valid reason for such behavior?

If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278803/how-does-elf-file-format-defines-the-stack), there is quite some stuff going into that address space before the user stack starts. Since you might need whole pages for this code for protection, there might be some overhead. Add library startup code and you might get quite a few bytes of memory.

Most of the code there is probably inherited copy-on-write (or even read-only) from the parent process.

Edit: On x64, any kernel-exported code probably go in the higher memory area. Don't claim what I have not verified ;-).

As a side note: When I compile and run your code on 64bit FreeBSD 10.2 I get this

```
0x7fffffffe5c8     0x7fffffffe5c4    0x7fffffffe5c0
c --> 0x7fffffffe5c0
b --> 0x7fffffffe5c4
a --> 0x7fffffffe5c8
```

which is similar to your output, even though FreeBSD seems to position the stack differently.

Running in 32bit mode, I get this:

```
0xffffd788     0xffffd784    0xffffd780
c --> 0xffffd780
b --> 0xffffd784
a --> 0xffffd788
```

The latter is probably really fun to explain (e.g. where is my kernel address space?).

Answer (score 1):

- variables can be stored at any address
- that address contains more than 32 bits, so it is assigning 64 bit
  addresses

Comment: In stack frame variables are stored in descending order

Comment: @SathishRam: this is wrong. The compiler will optimize and usually use a given call frame slot for several purposes (several variables which have the same address, because they are never used at the same time), and some variables are only kept in registers (without being spilled to the call frame)